# how can install swing/matisse on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, swing, matisse

i tried this link: http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/downloads/products/eworkbench/discovery-6.0/ 
but i'm fail how is this?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/vep/downloads/ is this better than swing/matisse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [**downloads.myeclipseide.com**](http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/),

> Direct access to the MyEclipse download area is not permitted.
>   Please go through the MyEclipse portal's **[download area](http://www.myeclipseide.com/ContentExpress-display-ceid-10.html)** to download MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench.

So you can load a full myeclipse distro, but not one plugin into a vanilla eclipse.

---

Aside from that, the <del>revived [Eclipse VE (Visual Editor)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE)</del> (archived since June 2011, now archive as a [sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/visualeditor/)) might be a good alternative

[image: visual editor]

You can install it [with Eclipse 3.5](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE/Update)

[image]

Comment: @Abhinav: I haven't tested the VE plugin in an Helios Eclipse yet, but the [update page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE/Update) has been edited 2 days ago, without mentioning any incompatibility, so there is hope.

Comment: @VonC, do you know if it is possible to get Matisse for regular Eclipse, not MyEclipse?

Comment: @amphibient no I don't. This could be a question in itself.